# PayPal tutorial missing references?

Tags: c#, paypal

Trying to follow the [PayPal .NET tutorial on GitHub](http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-NET-SDK/Samples/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx.html).

I've fixed it the best I can but still getting a lot of errors related to missing functions etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PayPal.Api;
using System.Configuration;
using PayPal.Sample.Utilities;
using System.Web.Providers.Entities;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for OAuthTokenCredential
/// </summary>
public class CredentialManager
{
    Dictionary<string, string> _Config = null;
    string _AccessToken = string.Empty;
    APIContext _APIConText = null;


    public CredentialManager()
    {
        // Get a reference to the config
        var config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();
        _Config = config;

        // Use OAuthTokenCredential to request an access token from PayPal
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(config).GetAccessToken();
        _AccessToken = accessToken;

        //API Context
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
        _APIConText = apiContext;

        // Initialize the apiContext's configuration with the default configuration for this application.
        apiContext.Config = ConfigManager.Instance.GetProperties();

        // Define any custom configuration settings for calls that will use this object.
        apiContext.Config["connectionTimeout"] = "1000"; // Quick timeout for testing purposes

        // Define any HTTP headers to be used in HTTP requests made with this APIContext object
        //if (apiContext.HTTPHeaders == null)
        //{
        //    apiContext.HTTPHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        //}
        //apiContext.HTTPHeaders["some-header-name"] = "some-value"; 
    }    

    public Payment GetPAyment(APIContext apiContext, string paymentid)
    {
        var payment = Payment.Get(apiContext, paymentid);

        return payment;
    }

    public bool CreatePayment()
    {
        try
        {
            bool Success = false;
            //var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
            string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(payerId))
            {
                var itemList = new ItemList()
                {
                    items = new List<Item>()
                    {
                        new Item()
                        {
                            name = "Item Name",
                            currency = "USD",
                            price = "15",
                            quantity = "5",
                            sku = "sku"
                        }
                    }
                };
                var payer = new Payer() { payment_method = "paypal" };
                var baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?";
                var guid = Convert.ToString((new Random()).Next(100000));
                var redirectUrl = baseURI + "guid=" + guid;
                var redirUrls = new RedirectUrls()
                {
                    cancel_url = redirectUrl + "&cancel=true",
                    return_url = redirectUrl
                };
                var details = new Details()
                {
                    tax = "15",
                    shipping = "10",
                    subtotal = "75"
                };
                var amount = new Amount()
                {
                    currency = "USD",
                    total = "100.00", // Total must be equal to sum of shipping, tax and subtotal.
                    details = details
                };
                var transactionList = new List<Transaction>();

                transactionList.Add(new Transaction()
                {
                    description = "Transaction description.",
                    invoice_number = Common.GetRandomInvoiceNumber(),
                    amount = amount,
                    item_list = itemList
                });

                var payment = new Payment()
                {
                    intent = "sale",
                    payer = payer,
                    transactions = transactionList,
                    redirect_urls = redirUrls
                };
                var createdPayment = payment.Create(_APIConText);
                var links = createdPayment.links.GetEnumerator();
                while (links.MoveNext())
                {
                    var link = links.Current;
                    if (link.rel.ToLower().Trim().Equals("approval_url"))
                    {
                        this.flow.RecordRedirectUrl("Redirect to PayPal to approve the payment...", link.href);
                    }
                }
                Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
                Session.Add("flow-" + guid, this.flow);
            }
            else
            {
                var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
                var paymentId = Session[guid] as string;
                var paymentExecution = new PaymentExecution() { payer_id = payerId };
                var payment = new Payment() { id = paymentId };
                var executedPayment = payment.Execute(apiContext, paymentExecution);
            }
            return Success;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting random errors on the following:

```
using PayPal.Sample.Utilities;
string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];
var baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + "/PaymentWithPayPal.aspx?";
invoice_number = Common.GetRandomInvoiceNumber(),   
Session.Add(guid, createdPayment.id);
Session.Add("flow-" + guid, this.flow);
var guid = Request.Params["guid"];
var paymentId = Session[guid] as string;
var executedPayment = payment.Execute(_APIConText, paymentExecution);
```

Errors:

- "Request" does not exist
- "Common" does not exist
- "flow" does not exist
- "session" is not valid in its current type

I think I'm just missing a reference or something. I'm trying to do it for C# ASP .Net (not MVC)

Comment: Looking at your questions I would say that you are very new to programming; in this case you need to start slow and learn the basics. If your `using` statement gives an error - it means you are missing a reference. If you attempt to use `Request` object that you never define - you will have a problem. Generally, nobody will want to walk you through all those errors unless you show that you at least *kinda* know what you are talking about

Comment: I'm following the tut posted on PayPal site and if you read I said I think I'm missing references. The issue is the references where never provided and I also moved this from a class to a page as well. Original idea was to make this a portable class.

Comment: Micah, I love this. You have one point at the time of my comment. I notice in my VS2015 if I hover over the underlined error it suggests possible fixes. Be careful, but if you see a "using" mentioned, then click that. You also might want to do a Tools > Nuget> Package Manager or one of the choices on the Nuget pop out. That will probably get the references you need. I think one of them is the PayPal install.

Answer (score 4):

You'll find the "Common" class [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/master/Samples/Source/Utilities/Common.cs)

Common.GetRandomInvoiceNumber() is just generating a random number. I think you would just replace that with your own generated invoice number.